# chrome.contextMenus.create with dynamic items

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I want to build a chrome extension that has a menu with some items based on what you click on.

i use `chrome.runtime.onConnectExternal` to pass the date, everything works fine in here. but as the messaging between extension and site is done async some time the events come after the menu gets shown. and it dose not update after that. 
the end result is that some times you see the menu based on the old item that was right clicked.

Is there a way to refresh the menu while open. or a way to comunicate between site and extension in a sync way?

Here is a example showing menu not updating:

```
const test = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    'title': `menu 0`,
    "contexts": ['all'],
});

let index = 0;

setInterval(() => {
    chrome.contextMenus.update(test, {title: 'menu ' + index++})
}, 1000);
```

Comment: 1) No 2) No. The only solution is to change the menu before it's shown by sending a message to your external app from a content script in `mousedown` event if event.button is 2, then notify the background page so it can update the context menu.

Comment: yes but i only know what element was clicked after the user rights click, and the notification to background its done async, i have no guarantee that the event will be received in background before the contextmenu is shown

Comment: The trick works because the context menu event is fired on mouseup so your code will have the extra time.

Comment: i use mousedown, but it dose not work 100%

Comment: Well, use `mouseover` event preemptively :-)